# Freeze database time in unittests (django & sqlite)

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, unit-testing

I have a query which generates a score based on the age of a view. As you can see I am doing the age calculation in the SQL. The query looks something like.

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(1.0 / (julianday('now') - julianday(view.date))) as score
FROM
    view;
```

In my unit tests I want to do something like

```python
self.assertEqual(actual_score, expected_score)
```

Normally, if I was doing the age calculation in python I could just freeze time with something like `django.test.utils.freeze_time`. However since the date diff is being done in SQL that is not a possibility.

How can I freeze time in my unit tests such that `julianday('now')` produces a configured value and I can accurately calculate the expected score.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite guarantees that all time functions inside the same query return the same time. However, this does not apply to multiple statements.

You could install your own user-defined function to replace `julianday()` (or whatever function(s) you are using). Alternatively, write your own [VFS](http://www.sqlite.org/vfs.html).

Comment: Are you implying that I am using multiple statements for `julianday`?

Comment: No. But that might be a useful guarantee if you use only relative times.